# how to pass parameter when calling WMI method in powershell

Tags: powershell, methods, parameters, wmi

The WMI method & parameter is described below.

```
WMI Method ID: 1
Input: uint8 InBuf[64]
Output: OutBuffer


Inbuf {
Uint32 var1;
Uint32 var2;
}
```

I have some PowerShell code that is using a WMI API.
The inbuf looks like a little strange, my script below get an methodinvocationexception error.

example:

```
$object=get-wimobject -class ACME -Namespace root\wmi -Impersonation Impersonate
[byte[]] $inbuf=3,0
$object.runm1($inbuf)
```

error:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

if change inbuf to below,

```
[byte[]] $inbuf={327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0}
```

more errors:

- [byte[]] $inbuf={327695;0},{65537;0},{65538;0},{131129;0},{327695;0}, ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
  ```
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
  ```

How to construct the call parameters to meet the requirements?

```
WMI Method ID: 1
Input: uint8 InBuf[64]
Output: OutBuffer


Inbuf {
Uint32 var1;
Uint32 var2;
}
```

Comment: `$inBuf = [Byte[]]::new(64)` where 64 is the capacity you need of the byte buffer

Comment: $inBuf = [Byte[]]::new(64) ; $inbuf=1;   report errors ''invalid parameters" , i have try 1,2..255, all the same error.

if the number greater than 255, i will report error:  Value was either too large or too small for system.byte[]

Comment: I don't understand that unit8 InBuf[64] defines two UNIT32 variables . How to create thi inbuf?

Comment: With `$inBuf = [Byte[]]::new(64)` you create an **array** of 64 bytes which are all valued `0`. To change any of these values, you must use the index, like `$inBuf[0] = 1`. Since these are Bytes (8-bit unsigned integers aka `unit8`), the value each element ranges from 0 to 255.